# In llvm is it possible to get the last storeinst for an alloca with respect to a load?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

E.g. if I have the following code:

```
alloca a;
store 3, a;
store 5, a;
%x = load a
```

Is it possible to get a pointer to the latest store, given the load instruction?

I know that this is not the exact llvm IR.

Comment: Are you assuming that the store is in the same basic block as the load?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it will be a start.

Comment: If it isn't in the same basic block, there's usually more than one possible store that could be the latest any given time that the load is reached. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

A very naive way would be getting the operand value

```
Value* llvm::LoadInst::getPointerOperand()
```

and back-iterating your code looking for it.

But I think that the Dominance Analysis gives you this kind of info.